# SocialPlugin cordova Whatsapp carriage return

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, whatsapp

I'm using SocialSharing Plugin (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) and I'm having problems with sharing a text message using

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(message, subject, null, null, callbackSuccess, callbackError)
```

function.

In particular, message contains character '\n'. This char is correctly recognized by other apps (such as Email, Facebook, Messenger, ecc..), but not with Whatsapp. 
I also tried to replace it native side with '\r\n' and `<br>` HTML tag, without success, whit this code:

```
NSString *message = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\r\n"];
```

Has anyone ever had this problem ?